# IEEE-754 Floating Point Standard: Representing Numbers

Tags: floating-point, binary, data-conversion, ieee-754

Given an IEEE-754 standard floating point number with **6 bits of exponent**, and **25 bits of mantissa.**

1: What's the smallest non-infinite positive integer this representation CANNOT represent? My answer:

- 2^-24

2: What power of 2 is the smallest representable positive value that is not a denormalized number? Submit the exponent only. My answer:

- -1022 since 1.0 × 2^-1022 ≈ 2.2 × 10^-308.

3: What power of 2 is the smallest representable positive value? Submit the exponent only. My answer: 1

4: How many NaNs can be represented with this floating point system? My answer: 16,777,214

5: What's the most negative possible denormalized number representable in this system? Write the value in hexadecimal (with uppercase letters), including the "0x" prefix. My answer: I don't know.

Please help me check my work and and better my understanding of floating point.

Comment: "What's the smallest non-infinite positive integer this representation CANNOT represent? My answer: 2^-24" looks wrong as 2^-24 is not an integer.

Comment: "Given an IEEE-754 standard floating point number with 6 bits of exponent, and 25 bits of mantissa." --> there is no such _IEEE-754 standard floating point number_.  Perhaps you want an encoding _like_ [IEEE-754 binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), but different in some ways.  IEEE-754 does not generally use _mantissa_.

Comment: 1. 6 bits of exponent and 25 bits of significand (“significand” is the preferred term; “mantissa” is an old word for the fraction portion of a logarithm) suggests there is also 1 sign bit (making 32 total), so the 25 bits are merely the primary encoding field for the significand, and the true significand is 26 bits. Then you know every integer from 0 to 2^26−1 can be represented. Can 2^26 be represented? What about 2^26+1? 2^26+2?

Comment: 2. With 6 bits for the exponent field, the field can encode values from 0 to 31. Usually, the bias is set to half that maximum, round down, so 15. The exponent code of 0 is used for subnormal values, so the code of 1 is the smallest code used for normal numbers. With an exponent code of 1 and a bias of 15, what is the true exponent? What is the smallest value the significand of a normal number can be? What do you get when you combine that significand and that exponent?

Comment: 3. Negative powers of two are allowed.

Comment: 4. The highest exponent code is used for infinities and NaNs. How many combinations of 32 bits have the exponent field set to its highest value? How many of those are used for infinities? How many does that leave left over for NaNs? (Also, do you count NaNs as different if they have different sign bits or they differ only in that one is signaling and one is quiet?)

Comment: 5. What is the sign of a denormalized number? What is the exponent code of a denormalized number? What exponent does that represent? (Hint: It is the same as for exponent code 1.) What is the greatest possible significand of a denormalized number?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am just down to solving number 5 now but I am really stuck on what it would be. The sign of a denorm number is 0. So i don't get what it would be

Comment: @BigMikefromLaos: I may have had a typo/thinko in that first question for 5. Also, the proper term is subnormal number, rather than denormalized (subnormal numbers are below the normal range; denormalized numbers are representations that are not in normal form even though they may be in the normal range, which is possible in some floating-point formats). For a negative subnormal number, you want the sign to be − (sign bit to be 1). Then go on to the other questions. What is the exponent code of a subnormal number? How big can the significand be?

Comment: 6 bits of exponent, and 25 bits of mantissa--Is there such an IEEE float?